# Unable to access Blob from Azure Virtual Machines

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I am unable to access Blob Service from Azure Virtual Machines running in the same region. I have created a storage account and planned to access to selected IP addresses i.e. MY Laptop, My Office PC and My Virtual Machine which is running is Azure. After whitelisting 3 of the IP's I am able to access the Blob Service from MY Laptop and MY Office PC but unable to access the same of Virtual Machine which is running in Azure.
Pl. let me know if anyone is facing similar issues and the resolution. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Unable? what is the error message?

Comment: There is no error as such. it is just unable to connect. Can you guide me further.

Comment: _something_ must give you a clue that you can't connect... what is that something? What are you actually doing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the NSG the VM belongs to and see if you are allowing the VM to communicate outbound, if so check if Azure storage is allowing incoming connections from the network to which the VM is connected to.

Comment: In VM NSG Outbound connection is allowed and also in Storage Accounts incoming connection I have added VM's Trusted IP but still it is unable to connect whereas if i try the same from other VM's which is in different location than Storage account it working fine. Also it is working fine from my laptop and office system after whitelisting their public IP's in Storage account.

Comment: Do you by chance have the error message I can look at?

Answer (score 0):

Your VM uses the internal network to attempt to access the Storage so adding the public IP won't work and you can't use internal IP's.

The easiest way would be adding the Virtual Network subnet of the VM to the firewall rules and add `Azure.Storage` as service endpoint to the subnet. If you add the subnet using the Azure Portal the service endpoint will be automatically added as well. Another way would be setting up a private endpoint.

Comment: I am able to successfully connect to storage accounts using private or service endpoint.
Is that means that if VM's and storage account are in the same region and if we enable the option "Selected Network" in the Storge account settings then using private or service endpoint is mandatory to connect to Storage account or there are other ways too.

Comment: When you are saying "VM uses the internal network to attempt to access the Storage" does it means that storage account has some private IP associated with it and when VM's in the same region as storage account tries to connect it uses storage accounts private IP to create connection. 
How Can we verify that storage account uses Internal private IP to connect. I mean is there any tool so that we can see.

Comment: @RoshanSharma Yes. Those are the only methods I'm aware of that would work for direct access. If you have turned on the diagnostics settings the `CallerIpAddress` when filtering on `StatusText == 'AuthorizationFailure'` should be able to tell you more.